# How to terminate a Cloud Code function when NodeJS http server times out?

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, parse-server

Given a Parse Server has a timeout set of 10s:

```
const httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
httpServer.timeout = 10 * 1000;
```

And a Cloud Code function is called that takes 20s to execute. NodeJS destroys the socket after 10s, but the Cloud Code function keeps on executing. Some cloud code functions are just wasting resources in that case and they should be aborted in a controlled manner, e.g. with certain breakpoints.

I could add a callback for when the timeout is fired:

```
httpServer.setTimeout(10 * 1000, {
  // Terminate Cloud Code, but how?
});
```

Is there a way to terminate the Cloud Code execution on timeout?

---

#### Update

A [feature request](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/6681) has been opened with Parse Server since there doesn't seem to be solution.

Comment: Is your cloud function written in node? Would process.exit not work in that context as well? https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code

Comment: Does `process` refer to the whole NodeJS process which runs the http server, or only to the request that the server is currently executing? Because I wouldn't want to kill the server. In the docs it says `the current Node.js process`.

Comment: > but the Cloud Code function keeps on executing. Some cloud code functions are just wasting resources in that case

If I'm understanding you, it's the Cloud Function you're looking to terminate? So the HTTP Server wouldn't be affected (providing it's not a cloud function), a cloud function is a process spawned each time it's required (then exited), so you'd be killing the node process within the cloud function I.E that execution. **Please check to ensure it's the cloud function though, and don't use process.exit in your HTTP server (Node.js API I assume?)**

Comment: To clarify the terminology, this question is related to Parse Server. Cloud Code is a specific functionality of Parse Server. The instance runs nodejs + express + nodejs http server (which runs the Parse Server app). The server is running continuously and executes a "Cloud Code" function which is a script of Parse Server when a specific endpoint is called. Only that script should be terminated. If the nodejs process is terminated, it appears to me that the http server + express would also be terminated?

Comment: A Cloud Code function is a script that is executed by Parse Server. I am not sure whether a separate node process is spun up for every Cloud Code request, a node expert would be helpful here :) But even then, keep in mind that we cannot just terminate the Cloud Code script, we have to terminate it controlled, because the script can execute writes which could lead to data inconsistency when just terminated at an arbitrary point of the script.

Comment: I'm understanding you now, do you declare your functions in the cloud/* directory? Can you put together a minimal repo? Are you wanting to exit execution client side? You *may* be limited by their implementation, but a child_process may be an option here. Node.js won't spin up another process, but Parse Server *may*. I'd need to review their implementation though.

Comment: Here is an example implementation: https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server-example. If you create a `/cloud/main.js` file and add a simple `Parse.Cloud.define(...)` that has an indefinite timeout, you can set the http server timeout at 10s and try to terminate. But again, when terminating the process, how would I make sure that it is terminated at a specific point in the script? We cannot just pull the plug on the script, as I said, that may lead to data inconsistencies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213568/discussion-between-isolated-and-manuel).